# Image is not displaying in lightning component for external users

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I tried using below codes, but the image is not appearing for external users

```
<img src="/resource/1450208160000/AccountImage" width="60" height="60"></img`>

<img src="/resource/AccountImage/Account.png" width="60" height="60"></img>

<img src="{!$ Resource.AccountImage}" width="60" height="60"></img>
```

Comment: Does your org has name space ?

Comment: @Mohit Shrivastava there is no name space in our org

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'Cache Control' field on your static resource. This must be set to "Public" for external users to be able to see the resource.

Comment: @ D.S 'Cache Control' field is public.